# PHP, EMAIL, Multiple Select drop down

Tags: php

Im having an issue with my first ever multiple select form. Ive read a lot of posts but cant figure out how to break the array out so that I can email the results of a multiple select form Here is what I have.

```
<select name="serv" id="serv" multiple>
 <option value = "Business Advocacy">Business Advocacy</option>
 <option value = "Business Planning & Advice">Business Planning & Advice</option>
 <option value = "Economic Development">Economic Development</option>
 <option value = "Export Assistance">Export Assistance</option>
```

In my php page I have the following:

```
function sendMail()   
{
 $org= $_POST['org'];
 $street= $_POST['street'];
 $city=  $_POST['city'];
 $state= $_POST['state'];
 $zip=  $_POST['zip'];
 $phone= $_POST['phone'];
 $ext= $_POST['ext'];
 $web=  $_POST['web'];
 $serv= $_POST['serv'];
 $description= $_POST['description'];
 $first= $_POST['first'];      
 $last=  $_POST['last'];
 $email= $_POST['email'];
 $position=  $_POST['position'];


 $to= 'myEmail@mail.com';
 $message = '<html><body>';
 $message .= '<h1>Organizational Request To Be Added To Website</h1>';
 $message .= 'Org:' . $org . '<br />';
 $message .= 'Street:' . $street . '<br />';
 $message .= 'City:' . $city . '<br />';
 $message .= 'State:' . $state . '<br />';
 $message .= 'Zip:' . $zip . '<br />';
 $message .= 'Phone:' . $phone . '<br />';
 $message .= 'Ext.:' . $ext . '<br />';
 $message .= 'Web:' . $web . '<br />';
 $message .= 'Serv:' . $serv . '<br />';
 $message .= 'Desc:' . $description . '<br />';
 $message .= 'First:' . $first . '<br />';
 $message .= 'Last:' . $last . '<br />';
 $message .= 'Email:' . $email . '<br />';
 $message .= 'Position:' . $position . '<br />';
 $message .='</body></html>';
 $subject = "Website Request";
 $message = $message;
 $headers = "From:" . $email . "\r\n";
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Problem I am having is figuring out how to email the $serv array contents. I tried using a for loop figuring that would be the easiest but I only get one of the contents mailed. Can someone take a look? I pulled out the forloop I had in there because it didnt work so I thought itd be easier to read with it removed.

Comment: Is your HTML supposed to be invalid?? (Second line) `<option value = "Business Advocacy</option>`

Comment: show  var dump of $serv array

Answer (score 1):

PHP's form data parser is a little … odd. It will only support multiple values for elements of a given name if that name ends in `[]`.

Change your HTML to:

```
<select name="serv[]" id="serv" multiple>
```

Then `$_POST['serv']` will be an arry that you can loop over.

Comment: Where would I put the for loop? Would it be in with the declared variables? Having a hard time figuring out how to make it work with the  email php code

Comment: An easy way would be to use implode. `$message .= 'Serv:' . implode(', ', $serv) . '<br />';`  A better way would be `$message .= 'Serv:' . (is_array($serv) ? implode(', ', $serv) : 'None selected') . '<br />';`

Comment: its telling me that there are invalid arguments passed when I use the 'easy way'

Comment: *Where would I put the for loop?* — You put it where you want to deal with the data.